# Google Cloud SDK Installer - Unzip Failed for Windows Installer

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install the Google Cloud SDK command-line interface using [Windows Installer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows).

Running the Windows installer on Windows 10 machine, it always gives the following error:

```
Unzip failed: Error opening ZIP file
```

[image]

There are many Stack Overflow questions with the exact issue, but none of them answers the question, there are only discussions.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell now why this was happening. I was on my Office WiFi while installation was going on, and there must have been some URL that the installer was trying to access but was blocked by my office firewall.

I tried the same from my home WiFi, and it worked as expected.